# Google play store is showing two different number of installs

Tags: android, google-play

My application wasn't in Google Play Store about one year for some issue and I had more than 50,000+ user before that became unpublished, but when I fixed them Google accepted my app again and it is published one month ago.
Right now, my number installs isn't the same in Google Play Console and Play Store, actually, play store shows 50,000+ installs yet after one month.
Do you know how Google Play compute the number of installs? and why are they different?
I have to point out that my app has been active in other android app stores, and I think google play is computing all of their installs by tracking user devices, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The install or uninstalls reflects google developer console in few days may be 3-4 days or more. And it also takes another few days to show in google play store.

You can check in developer console. If it is increasing, this will definitely reflect correctly in few days.

Comment: I said my friend, it takes one month ago till now :)

Comment: @mhadikz , is those number is increasing in developer console? Actually , I had faced same issue, but it automatically got resolved.

Comment: yeah it is, but the play store installs has incredibly different than developer console